# Dynamic content - transitions NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright let's see if I can explain this properly.

I am writing my own jQuery photo gallery. It loads the contents of the gallery using AJAX, calling upon a Web Method which returns a string which is an array filled with JSON objects containing data (i.e. the file name and the file path of the image and the file path for the image's thumbnail) on every file in the folder passed to it.

Like 'a so:

```
$(".Title").click(function (e) {

    Populate($(this).text());

    function Populate(folder) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Filenames.asmx/GetFiles",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{ "folderName" : "'+folder+'"}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }   
        });
    }
    ...//more code follows
```

Anyway, so, we have our `OnSuccess()` function:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var $thumbs = $('#Gallery_Top .viewPane .thumbPanel');
    images = $.parseJSON(response.d);

   $thumbs.children().each(function () {
        //$(this).animate({ 'width': '0px', 'opacity': '0' }, 500).remove();
        $(this).transition({ opacity: 0 }).remove();
    });

    //make sure the thumb reel resets to its original position
    $thumbs.css('left', '0px');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        InsertHTML(images[i].thumbHref);
    }               
}
```

So far so good.

In the `InsertHTML()` function, I have to do a few things...

```
function InsertHTML(data) {
    //create the thumbnail image
    var $thumb = $('<img src="' + data + '" alt=""/>');

    //set its default class to inactive
    $thumb.addClass('inactive');

    //bind a function to the thumbnail's click event
    $thumb.bind("click", function () {
        //make sure we have the current image assigned
        //for navigation purposes.
        $currentImage = $(this);

        //remove the main image from the viewing pane
        $('#Gallery_Top .viewPane .mainImage .showImage').children().animate({'opacity':'0'},500,'easeOutSine').remove();

        //set all of the thumbnails to inactive
        $(this).parent().children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            }
        });

        //set the clicked thumbnail active
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //get the URL for the related image
        var href = data.replace('Thumbs\\', '');
        href = href.replace('_thumb', '');
        var $image = $('<img src="' + href + '" alt=""/>');
        $image.addClass('mainImg');

        $('#Gallery_Top .viewPane .mainImage .showImage')
            .append($image)
            .animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 500, 'easeInSine');

    });
    $('#Gallery_Top .viewPane .thumbPanel').append($thumb);

}
```

Okay, so anyway, what's not working is every transition after the first time I click a thumbnail image. The first time I click a thumbnail, the photo fades in nicely. Ever after that, there's no transition at all.

Been yanking my hair out for about 3 hours trying to figure out a way around.

By the way, here's some CSS.

```
.mainImg{
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Okay now I'm having even more problems.... stand by...I'm probably gonna have to edit this again.

Answer (score 0):

EUREKA SUCCESS I DID IT.

It never fails. I beat my head against a wall for three or four hours, trying so hard not to have to come on here and ask, then half an hour after I finally break down and ask a question, I figure it out. It's probably motivation from the shame of not knowing how to do something.

```
                    var $image = $('<img src="' + href + '" alt=""/>');
                    $image.on('load', function () {
                        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 500, 'easeOutSine');
                    });
                    $image.addClass('mainImg');
                    $image.css('opacity', '0');
                    $('#Gallery_Top .viewPane .mainImage .showImage').append($image);
```

Comment: Now if someone could just point me in the direction of how to get it to fade out when the image is removed, that'd be just super swell.